# How pass parameter when navigate to another page (Shell)

Tags: android, maui, app-shell

I've just started trying to use MAUI in Visual studio to develop a multiplatform app. I have managed to use shell navigation and this works well using the flyout.

What I want to do is have a button click which navigates to another page passing a varialbe with it.

What does work (kind of) is this:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ResultListView(ordnum));
```

This does navigate to the page and passes the var ordnum as I want, however it breaks out of the shell navigation (I loose the flyout etc).

What I can't figure out is how to do it within Shell

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync
```

seems to be what I want, but when I use routings I can't specify the variable in the same way?

This seems such a basic question I'm sure it's been asked before, but I honestly can't find it. I've spent all morning searching for an answer! The answers I did find about passing variables through XAML were very confusing.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lest supose you want to send an object **PRODUCT**

```
private Product productToSend;
private Product anotherProductToSend;

await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(YourPageHere)}?",
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["Object1"] = productToSend,
                    ["Object2"] = anotherProductToSend
                });
```

Then in your pageViewModel:

```
[QueryProperty("Object1", "Object1")]
[QueryProperty("Object2", "Object2")]
public partial class YourPageHereViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    Product Object1;

    [ObservableProperty]
    Product Object2;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the tips, I'm still struggling to get this to work. Do I have to use a View Model? Currently I do not have any view models, I just have 2 pages I want to navigate to, this works fine: await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ResultListView(ordnum)); but breaks out of the shell navigation.

Comment: Is this the only way to do this? Do I have to have a page ViewModel? My app is becoming cluttered with ViewModels and all I want is to get at the data passed

Comment: @AndrewTaylor viewmodel it's the easy way to do it, if not you can pass data via contructor when you call your page!

Comment: @djack109 i will make you an example to pass data without viewmodel, give me some minutes plz

Comment: @LeandroToloza did you have an example of how to do this without using a view model? My app is a very basic idea and I’m stuck on the most simple part!

Comment: I resorted to using viewmodels, which seems to overcomplicate everything for such a simple function. But now, I can bind the view model to the view. So I can bind a string called count to a label in XAML, this works well.... but how to I access this parameter in viewmodel without referencing the label? I can do this: Debug.WriteLine(MainLabel.Text) and have it bound to the string count, but I can't do this Debug.WriteLine(Count). I'm very confused!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get Leandro's answer to work in MVVM with communityToolkit (because of case sensitivity issues). This is what worked for me:

Pay close attention to the lower / upper case on the variables.

Parent viewModel

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
```

....

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    public AirPlane selectedPlane;

    ....

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Tap(AirPlane sender)
    {
        SelectedPlane = sender;

        var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["EditAirplane"] = SelectedPlane
        };

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(EditPlanePage)}", navigationParameter);

    }
```

Child viewModel

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
public partial class EditPlaneViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    AirPlane editAirplane;

    public EditPlaneViewModel()
    { 
    
    }

    public void SetEditPlane(AirPlane incomingAirplane)
    { 
        EditAirplane = incomingAirplane;

        //reload list async here
    }
 .....
```

Childpage.cs

```
public partial class EditPlanePage : ContentPage, IQueryAttributable
{
    private AirPlane _editAirplane;

    public EditPlanePage(EditPlaneViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _vm = vm;

        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        _editAirplane = query["EditAirplane"] as AirPlane;
        _vm.SetEditPlane(_editAirplane);
    }

 ....
```